# Автоматическая смена фона для секции

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать для секции фон (состоит из двух картинок) который меняется каждые 6 секунд через Background? Если возможно, подскажите со скриптом.

```
<section class="first">
</section>
.first
{
    background: #acfbfd;
    background: red;
    background: url(..//img/first/2bg.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 700px;
    padding: 70px 20px 70px 0;
}
.one
{
    background: #acfbfd;
    background: url(..//img/first/1bg.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 700px;
    padding: 70px 20px 70px 0;
}
$(function()
{
    setInterval(function()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например такой код, **переписано**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>titile</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>
.one {
   background-image: url('http://36.media.tumblr.com/ddfa95b0f361df3848c8b58dc22ac27b/tumblr_nycdzlHYnu1sus0wio1_500.jpg');
  }
  div {
   background-image: url('http://vsefacty.com/uploads/interesnye_fakty_o_planete_zemlya_1.jpg');
   width: 500px;
   height: 333px;

   background-color: #acfbfd;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
 </style>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function(){

   setInterval(function(){
    $('div').toggleClass('one');
   }, 3000);

  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div>Секция</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Могли бы Вы подсказать, какая разница между toggleClass и addClass ?

Comment: add - добавить, toggle  - переключатель, если есть: убрать, если нет: добавить.

Comment: почему-то не работает

Comment: Фон меняется, но если у первого изображения свойство background: cover работает, у второго почему-то нет, можно ли это как-то исправить ? Изображения по размеру одинаковые.

Comment: в скрипте меняется только background-image, остальные background-свойства пропишите сами.

Comment: Дело в том, что я их прописал, но изображение не наследует эти свойства.

Comment: @SvArt713 кода не вижу

Comment: Добавил код в основной вопрос.

Comment: @SvArt713 дописал.